# ajax complete unexpected token '('

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: fburl,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                var html = '';

                $.each(data["data"], function () {

                    html += '<div class="box albumCover" rel="' + this.id + '">';
                    html += '<div class="album" style=\'background: url("http://graph.facebook.com/' + this.cover_photo
                        + '/picture?type=normal") no-repeat center center; background-size: cover; \'>';
                    html += '<div class="titleWrap"><div class="titleBox">' + this.name + '</div></div></div></div>';
                });

                $("#albums").append(html);



            }, complete: function (){
                alert('done');
            }); // here
```

What's wrong here with my ajax's complete? I got unexpected token ')' at the last line of above code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not properly close out the config object parameter of the `$.ajax` function.

You need an extra `}` on the last line:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: fburl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        .
        .
        .
    }, complete: function () {
        alert('done');
    } // your code only closed out this function
}); // and not this object
```

Comment: @Fernandez, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it by pressing the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to put your code into **[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)** and save it as `.js` file. Then check your code brackets.

```
complete: function (){
    alert('done');
} //you were not closing your complete function.
```

Comment: "you were not close this function" is unclear - it implies that the `complete` function wasn't closed, but it's actually the `$.ajax({...` which wasn't closed.

Comment: You don't really "have" to put the code in Notepad++, however that is a good option.